# Mocking parameter test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am trying to test if the parameters passed to an interface are correct:

```
MailMessage expectedMailMessage = new MailMessage();

var mailerMock = new Mock<IMailSender>();
mailerMock.Setup(m => m.Send(expectedMailMessage)).Verifiable();

Mailer mailer = new Mailer(mailerMock.Object);
mailer.Send(expectedMailMessage);

mailerMock.Verify(m => m.Send(expectedMailMessage), Times.Once());
```

Mailer class:

```
public class Mailer : IMailer
{
    private readonly IMailSender _mailSender;
    public Mailer(IMailSender mailSender)
    {
        _mailSender = mailSender;
    }

    public void Send(MailMessage mailMessage)
    {
        _mailSender.Send(mailMessage);
    }
}
```

But still this fails, problem is that it is very hard to debug. I checked if there is some random Guid generated or a date is set, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Are you sure you should be passing the mock object to Send() method?

Comment: you need to post the code from inside the mailer as the problem is there.

Comment: I agree with Ufuk. It seems very strange that `Send()` apparently takes a Mock object as argument? Are you sure that is correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct, I updated my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some fiddling I gave up and come up with this:

```
mailerMock.Verify(m => m.Send(It.Is<MailMessage>(msg => msg.Subject == expectedMailMessage.Subject));
mailerMock.Verify(m => m.Send(It.Is<MailMessage>(msg => msg.Sender == expectedMailMessage.Sender));
```

Also easier to see on which property it is failing.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `mailerMock` instead of `expectedMailMessage` to your `Send` method:

```
Mailer mailer = new Mailer(mailerMock.Object);
mailer.Send(expectedMailMessage);
```

Comment: Sorry that was a typo on my side.

Comment: @Rogier21 looks like you did not provide your actual code, because Moq by default will compare actual and expected parameters by reference. If you are passing `expectedMailMessage`, then test should not fail.

Comment: That is what I thought, but for this example it doesn't work, but I can't figure out why not.

Comment: @Rogier21 I still think you passed some other object to `Send` method, not one created at the start of test.